# All packets have router IP when they arrive at kerio control

Tags: networking, router, ip, firewall, kerio

I have four sites on my network, each site has a microtik router that connect them together. I only have one internet connection at my central office. My internet is connected to Kerio Control firewall along with my central office router. I configured the Kerio to give internet only to specific users. But as all client traffics go through router, they all have router IP. If I login on a client, all clients use that account. Because from firewall sight of view, they all have same IP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You only have two options:

- Adjust your site-to-site connection settings to not NAT each site to a single IP. This can require some subnetting and routing knowledge, and really depends on how the sites are configured
- Use a different form of user authentication in Kerio Control ([docs](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/control/content/server-configuration-kerio-control/authenticating-users-to-kerio-control-1811.html)) like radius or via proxy settings instead of by device IP